# add values from listbox to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, listbox

I have a problem that the value of listbox don't add into the database.

i have a checkboxlist and listbox, first i want to add all selected checkbox value in listbox, it works successfuly, and then i want to add that data of listbox come form checkboxlist to database on button click event, it do not work so how to solve this.

```
<div id="contentwrapper" class="contentwrapper">

            <div id="validation" class="subcontent">

                    <form class="stdform stdform2" style="border-top:solid 1px #ddd">

                        <p>
                            <label>Hotel Name</label>
                            <span class="field">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHotel" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </span>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                            <legend class="legend">Facilities</legend>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblFacility" runat="server" DataTextField="FacilityName" DataValueField="FacilityID" TextAlign="Right" RepeatColumns="5">
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>

                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        </p>
                        <p  class="stdformbutton">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="radius2" Text="Add" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
                        </p>                            
                    </form>                        
            </div><!--subcontent-->

        </div><!--contentwrapper-->            
        <div id="Div1" class="contentwrapper">              
            <div id="Div2" class="subcontent">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <form class="stdform stdform" style="border-top:solid 1px #ddd">
                        <p>                             
                            <span class="field">
                                <asp:ListBox ID="lstFacility" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox><br />
                            </span>
                        </p>                            
                        <p  class="stdformbutton">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="submit radius2" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div><!--subcontent-->            
        </div>
```

AND .cs file is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "my connection string";

        if (Session["admin"] != null)
        {
            lblEmail.Text = Session["adminEmail"].ToString();
            lblAdmin.Text = "Wel Come " + Session["admin"].ToString();
            lblAdmin1.Text = "Wel Come " + Session["admin"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["hotelID"] != null)
            {
                ddlHotel.SelectedValue = Session["hotelID"].ToString();
            }
            ddlHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectAll(myConnectionString);
            ddlHotel.DataTextField = "HotelName";
            ddlHotel.DataValueField = "HotelID";
            ddlHotel.DataBind();
            ddlHotel.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel");

            BindData();
        }
    }


    private void BindData()
    {
        string myConnectionString = "my connection string";    
        cblFacility.DataSource = dalMST_Facility.SelectAll(myConnectionString);
        cblFacility.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1 = string.Empty;
        lstFacility.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ListItem item in this.cblFacility.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                lstFacility.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "my connection string";

        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            DataTable dt = dalMST_FacilityTran.SelectAll(myConnectionString);
            int cnt = dt.Rows.Count;
            entMST_FacilityTran.HotelID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHotel.SelectedValue);
            entMST_FacilityTran.FacilityID = 0;

            entMST_FacilityTran.Created = DateTime.Now;
            entMST_FacilityTran.Modified = DateTime.Now;

            #region Insert,Update

            for (int i = 0; i < lstFacility.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                int flag = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++)
                {
                    int hotelid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j][2].ToString());
                    int facilityid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j][1].ToString());


                    if (lstFacility.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        entMST_FacilityTran.FacilityID = Convert.ToInt32(lstFacility.Items[i].Value);

                        if (entMST_FacilityTran.HotelID == hotelid && entMST_FacilityTran.FacilityID == facilityid)
                        {
                            flag = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    if (dalMST_FacilityTran.Insert(entMST_FacilityTran, myConnectionString))
                    {
                        //txtFacility.Text = "";
                        //Response.Redirect("AddFacility.aspx");

                        //return;
                    }
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect("AddRoomCategory.aspx");


            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Have U got any error?

Comment: no there is no any error but record is not insert into database

Comment: plz use try and catch block on submit button. So u can get error if there is any. ur code looks fine.

Comment: thanks hitesh, bus in this code the click event is not fired.The cursor don't go to the button click event.

Comment: Ok that was issue for not inserting data into database

Comment: yes that is a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41307/discussion-between-hitesh-and-vipul-parmar)

Comment: i am in chat right now

Comment: Hello hitesh i cant chat with you i nee some reputation first i will chat with you sorry for not reply.

Comment: How many reputaion u need to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem related to update panel.

Use below code:

```
 <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" EventName="Click" />
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" /> 
 </Triggers>
```

So submit button cilck event will fire.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First You have to remove Nested For Loop**

```
 String lstName;

 for (int i= 0; i< listBoxEmployeeName.Items.Count;i++)
    {

    lstName=listBoxEmployeeName.Items[i].Text;//Here your value stored in lstName
    //here continue you insert query  

    }
```

Comment: i use nested for loop because i do not want to add record that is already in database.

Comment: Have u use any validaton on page?